# Checking the reverse IP address to find all DNS records

Tags: vulnerability, dns, ip

In the context of Vulnerability Assessment, what is the purpose of checking the reverse IP address of an end-point to find all DNS records of ‘A’ type associated with the IP?

I've come across this method whilst reading a vulnerability assessment report but puzzled by what purpose it really serves.

Comment: Reverse DNS is a weak way to try to enumerate resources and find "internal" names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform a vulnerability assessment you first need an inventory of what you are assessing. Reverse ip lookups for dns entries are one way to start building that inventory.